# Hide the "choosable file filter" widget in a JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

How do I hide the "choosable file filter widget" in a JFileChooser?  By "choosable file filter widget", I mean the panel below containing the words "File Format".

[image]

There's lots of info in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) on how to modify the specific filters that appear in the widget, but I can't figure out how to hide it entirely.

I'm using the JFileChooser to select a directory, so the widget's unnecessary.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

In the end I took Andrew Thompson's suggestion and set the filter chooser to display the text "directories only".  In case it helps anyone, I used the following code:

```
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        fc.setFileFilter( new FileFilter(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File f) {
                return f.isDirectory();
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Directories only";
            }

        });
```

Comment: Right... I didn't think of that. Not a bad idea at all. Thx.

Comment: BTW - I decided "Any Folder" was a much more user-friendly way to state "Directories only".  ;)

Comment: Well you're just full of good ideas. I'm going to use that one, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternately fill it with a "Directories only" text. Then it will appear as the user expects it, with instructions.

---

**File Format:** <kbd>Any Folder</kbd>

---